# Removing Tail-Recursion from Method (Java)

Tags: java, optimization, tail-recursion

I have this method:

```
    private String computePerm(int iteration) {
        if (iteration < n + 1) {
            return Character.toString((char) (iteration + 48));
        } else {
            if (iteration % n == 0) {
                return computePerm((iteration / n) - 1) + computePerm(((iteration - 1) % n + 1));
            } else {
                return computePerm(iteration / n) + computePerm(iteration % n);
            }
        }
   }
```

It computes a permutation induced by a single breadth-first search traversal. I'm using it to solve [Post's correspondence problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post_correspondence_problem). However, I suspect it is tail-recursive, and it seems to incur an ugly overhead on some instances of the problem.

How can I remove tail-recursion while preserving the method's behavior?

Comment: There are 4 recursive calls in your method. That's not tail recursion.

Comment: @shmosel Then how do I remove recursion in the first place? I honestly can't seem to do it that way, because I suspect it would be quite a bit faster.

Comment: Who said you can? And why are you convinced it would be faster?

Comment: @shmosel I'm not convinced of anything, but it has been my experience that recursion tends to be fairly expensive in Java as opposed to just looping.

Answer (score -1):

This does what you're after (the permutation of an alphabet of size *n*):

```
private static String computePerm(int iteration) {
    return Integer.toString(iteration, n);
}
```

Comment: I don't think that's what I'm looking for at all. Sorry.

Comment: `computePerm()` generates a permutation of your alphabet, which has size _n_, right? I assume you're using it to generate token pairs to test your solution on. `Integer.toString(i, radix)` does the same thing as your method. Look at its source if you want an example of an iterative solution to your problem, or just use the call if you only need it to set up test data.